# Book Identification with an Ice Planet

Tags: story-identification, books

This may not be possible, because I really only remember the cover. I was in grade school, so early nineties I would think, and it was a sci-fi book. The cover was mostly blue to indicate ice, it was drawn as opposed to a photography. The most obvious point about the cover is there was what I believe to be an alien being, with the body of a snowball, wings of like a bird or penguin, and a blue face and legs somewhat humanoid. It wasn't that long of a book, probably < 100 pages or around 100 pages. These beings were on another planet, and there were humans in the story I think.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds very much like the Icerigger trilogy by Alan Dean Foster (First book "Icerigger" from 1978). In at least one illustration, the second book in the trilogy "Mission to Moulokin" features an alien (Tran) on the cover with skin stretched between its upper and lower limbs similar to a flying squirrel. The bottom of the Tran feet have an adapted Claw which functions like an ice skate. The Tran use the skin like a sail to propel themselves across the ice of their ice covered home world Trần-Ky-Ky.

Below are some images of various book covers for the series. Any of these ring a bell?

http://www.google.com/search?q=icerigger&lr=&as_qdr=all&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=9ykAU8CjBIujkQfyyoHABg&ved=0CHMQ7Ak

Comment: no sorry, I don't think that was it, this may have been more of a children's book.

Comment: 'k.  Sorry that wasn't it. Good luck.

Comment: ok thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the mid-90s there was a series by Richard Moran about a new modern Ice Age. Some of the cover variants sound very similar to what you describe, but I don't remember a penguin-like creature on any of them. Try a search on "An Empire of Ice" or "Earth Winter".